# Launch GUI application on remote host (Linux CentOS 8) via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, gnome

I'm having some questions trying to run an GUI app remotely from SSH. My Linux skills are limited and I'm having some issues trying to achieve it through the following scenario:

I have a host with CentOS 8 and GNOME GUI attached to a TV, no mouse or keyboard attached to it (that's the remote host, I will call it SERVER). I also have the local host with a SSH client (the SSH).

What I'm trying to do:

Using SSH, I want to unlock the Welcome screen that's showing in the TV attached to the SERVER, then I want to launch Retroarch (to load it on the TV connected to SERVER). How do I login in the SERVER to get out of the GNOME Welcome screen? Using the command:

```
loginctl unlock-sessions
```

only works if I turn on SERVER, plug a keyboard, login and wait until the screen locks because of inactivity. Also, when launching RETROARCH via SSH, I found 2 ways to do it that "kind of work", using DISPLAY=:0 and nohup, but they both lock the process to the SSH session (besides the fact it locks the terminal or the process to the SSH session, it only works if I already logged in the SERVER and passed the Welcome screen). Is there a way to launch it as if I was running the app directly from SERVER?

Comment: You might consider starting VNC via ssh and connecting via VNC to change stuff in the current X session.

Comment: https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/login-automatic.html.en https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/User#Automatic_login_into_Xorg_without_display_manager

Answer (score 0):

to interface with window manager such as Gnome remotely you need to consider running a VNC session because to my knowledge the window managers are not designed to be controlled via SSH + CLI.

If you are running Gnome over X11 then you should consider using X11-vnc which will expose the current X11 session to you remotely - i. e. you will see the same picture via VNC as on TV connected to the SERVER.

If you are running on Wayland you will need to do your own Internet research what's X11-vnc Wayland replacement..

for the 1st case these are the steps :

Server:

```
apt install x11-vnc -y
x11-vnc
```

Client :

```
apt install tigervnc-viewer -y
ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 <SERVER-IP>
vncviewer localhost:5901
```

it's best practice to wrap VNC protocol in a ssh tunnel therefore many VNC servers listen by-default only on localhost. Port number of VNC may change but it's established to start from 5900.